# ant delete task with wildcard not working

Tags: ant, wildcard, build.xml

I would like to set up an ant task to delete all .class and .jar
    files from the same directory the build.xml file is, including
    nonsense.class which is in the same directory as the build.xml
    file. So I've set up the following build.xml file for ant 1.9.0
    as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="HelloWorld" default="deploy">
  <!-- ... -->
  <target name="clean">
    <delete file="nonsense.class" />
    <delete file="*.class" />
    <delete file="*.jar" />
  </target>
</project>
```

When I execute it nonsense.class is removed but none of
the other .class or .jar files. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17):

You need to use a fileset to delete more than one file:

```
  <target name="clean">
    <delete file="nonsense.class" />
    <delete>
      <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="*.class"/>
        <include name="*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
    </delete>
  </target>
```